# How can I instruct windows to report the name of my java app instead of java.exe

Tags: java, windows, security, firewall

Firewall problem:
When I run a jar or a class in windows, windows reports it as java.exe.
How can I instruct windows to report it with the name of the jar or class.

Eg. java -jar myapp.jar

The firewall sees it as java.exe. The problem is that I cannot allow any jar to pass thru the firewall.

Comment: but...but... Java.exe is the application... Unless you compile it as an exe, Java.exe is going to have to run it, compile it, etc...  Good Question Though.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your Java application in its own executable.

There are a number of tools that will generate this executable for you. My favorite is [exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html).  Others are listed in many other stackoverflow questions about creating an executable for a Java program, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file).

Comment: Thanks Andy. But it was not the kind of solution I was after... I know about those tools. I didn't want to loose my portability.

Comment: You can make a \*.exe wrapper *and* keep portability for other operating systems. I've done this while delivering on Windows and OS X and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a launcher EXE properly named which runs your code.  Launch4j can do this if properly configured, but with an extra step with temp files at launch time.

Comment: Thanks. (see comment above)